# Godot Camera shake without target

Tags: camera, godot

I'm working with godot 3.2 to make this [screen shake](https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/2d/screen_shake/), but my issue is that i don't have a target, like in the example, in the example code, it's a kinematic body that is being followed by the camera, i don't have that, i'm  making a match-three type of game, so i don't use those.

What i tried it's to use the main node, in which the game loop logic is executed but the camera shake didn't work, also tried with another elementsd but it failed beacuse they are mostly HUD elements
and shows an error about global positions.

Also i not sure how to get the board/grid, since it's instantiated by code.
How i can make shake camera without a target or get a similar effect?

Comment: It doesn't look like the target is used for anything shake-related in that code, so you could simply omit any lines referring to the target. How have you tried to do this so far?

Comment: It is very easy to remove the lines related to the target, as DMGregory mentions. Furthermore, the noise version of the code does not use a target, you should be able to use that one without modification. It should also be possible to add a node just to be a target if you really want to.